# what's needed in asp file for xmlhttp request to save data to a database

Tags: javascript, ajax, database, asp-classic

I need to use JavaScript to send data to be stored in a database. Having looked around on-line I think the best way was to use a xmlhttp request to send data to an asp file.
Below is the script I've got to send to 'Receiver.asp'.
Searching the web hasn't helped me uncover the code I need in Receiver.asp.

```
function postToASP(name, time) {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
var UrlToSend = "Receiver.asp?" +"n=" + name + "t=" + time ; 
xmlhttp.open("GET", UrlToSend, false);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Some additional info if needed:

- the majority of my code is written in processing
- the above js script and the .asp file will be stored in same folder as sketch
- eventually i intend to run on a xampp server

Comment: `"t=" + time` should be `"&t=" + time`. Name value pairs in query string are separated using `&`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm assuming that that's supposed to be client side JavaScript and that it works.

You say you want to use XAMPP.  Forget it. Classic ASP is proprietary Microsoft technology which will only run on IIS.

What Receiver.asp has to do is quite simple.  First it has to use the request object to retrieve the data it has been sent.  (I'm using VBScript as my scripting language because it's what I'm used to, you can use Javascript if you prefer

```
dim time, name
time = Request.Querystring("t")
name = Request.Querystring("n")
```

If you were using the post method then you would use `Request.Form()` Alternatively `Request()` works for both get and post methods.

Then it's a standard database insert.  It doesn't matter if the data is sent in a querystring, in an html form or by an ajax call, the server side code is pretty much the same. Here's a simple tutorial, you should find plenty more if you google

http://www.codefixer.com/tutorials/form_to_database.asp

You haven't said what sort of database you want to write to.  You'll need the relevant connection string.  Here's a very useful resource with an easy to remember url.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/